# Win7 Batch command not working

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have this code in batch (gitcopyfiles.bat) file which tracks modified files of git and copies them to a specified folder but it doesn't work:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %A in (`git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-only
--diff-filter=ACMRT HEAD~1 HEAD`) do echo FA|xcopy "%~fA" "C:\git_changed_files\%A"
```

But it doesn't work **however** when I run the above command directly from command prompt, it does work well. So it doesn't work only in batch file.

Can anyone help what could be wrong ? I even tried running bat file as administrator but still no luck

The error message that comes on bat file is:

```
~fA" "C:\git_changed_files\A" was unexpected at this time.

D:\wamp\www\myproject>for /f "usebackq tokens=*" ~fA" "C:\git_changed_files\A"
```

Comment: I assume you meant it **does** work in command prompt - the main reason I see is the use of `%A` instead of `%%A` there are multiple differences between CMD and batch file execution of the code

Comment: @SmokeyPHP: Tried changing `%A` to `%%A` but still didn't work. Could be with slashes or something ?

Comment: I've never run a command that uses flags like `--no-commit` but I know that when I've used special characters in an `in()` command such as the pipe (`|`) I've had to escape it like so: `^|` (like this for example, `in ('ipconfig ^| find "address"')`

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: @Endoro: I have updated the question with error message that comes.

Comment: As the error comes after the single % sign around `xcopy "%` did you also change that one to double % ? (`%%@fA`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a run:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRT HEAD~1 HEAD') do xcopy "%%A" "C:\git_changed_files\"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
do echo FA|xcopy "%~fA" "C:\git_changed_files\%A"
```

1. `echo FA|` is not necessary, remove it
2. `"%~fA"` might not work, if the path to the file is not set
3. `\%A"` is not necessary, remove it
4. `for /f "usebackq tokens=*"` should be `for /f "usebackq delims="`

Comment: Thanks for answer but issue still there: I now have modified like you said: `for /f "usebackq delims=" %A in (`git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRT HEAD~1 HEAD`) do xcopy "C:\git_changed_files"` but it gives error still `\git_changed_files" was unexpected at this time.
D:\wamp\www\givingcircle>for /f "usebackq delims=" \git_changed_files"`

Comment: Note: it should be `%%A` when in a batch file, `%A` on the command line